# How do I turn only the first letter uppercase?

Tags: python

I have this:

```
word = raw_input("enter a word")
word[0].upper()
```

But it still doesn't make the first letter uppercase.

Comment: Strings are immutable. `str.upper()` returns a *new* string with the alteration made. You ignored that return value.

Comment: what is wrong with the `str.capitalize()` method?

Answer (score 1):

`.upper()` returns a new string because strings are immutable data types. You ought to set the return value to a variable.

You can use `.capitalize` over `.upper` if you want to make only the first letter uppercase.

```
>>> word = raw_input("enter a word")
>>> word = word.capitalize()
```

Please note that `.capitalize` turns the rest of the characters to lowercase. If you don't want it to happen, just go with `[0].upper()`:

```
word = word[0].upper() + word[1:]
```

Comment: `word.title()` might also work.